# Cannot make namespace work for main django app

Tags: django

## TL;DR

I want to use namespaces for all of my django apps. It works fine for all the regular apps, but I get a "NoReverseMatchError: 'myproject' is not a registered namespace" for my main project app. Is there anything specific to this app that causes the namespace to not work?

## Details

I just started a new django app and I'm using namespaces for the first time. My project tree is as follow (only relevant files and directories included):

```
myproject/
├── myproject/
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   └── home.html
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── urls.py
└── app1/
    ├── templates/
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

My urls.py files are as follows:

myproject/urls.py

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from myproject import views


app_name = 'myproject'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('app1/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app1/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path

from app1 import views


app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

When calling `{% url 'app1:login' %}` or `return redirect('app1:login')` everything works fine. However, when I try to use `{% url 'myproject:home' %}` or `return redirect('myproject:home')`, I get a "NoReverseMatchError: 'myproject' is not a registered namespace".

My questions are:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is it not possible to use namespaces for the main app of project? And why not? I'd really like to have a full understanding of how Django operates.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get to the `home` url, you can just do `{% url 'home'%}`.
The core does not take namespaces.

If you need to access URL's from app1, with the namespace `myproject`, try the following:

Try the following:

```py
#  path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
path('app1/', include('app1.urls'), name="myproject"),
```

To find more information about Django namespaces, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

*Edit*

After some looking in the docs, maybe a [solution like the one at the bottom of the doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) will help?

The example shown:

```
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

polls_patterns = ([
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
], 'polls')

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include(polls_patterns)),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to find an alternative but I ended up giving up because I believe the answer lies in your first sentence: the core does not take namespaces. I wish I could have a better undestanding as to why.